# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor de una columna si se cumple una condición?

Tags: r, if, rstudio

Tengo un `data frame` en R y mi pregunta es: ¿cómo poder cambiar el valor de una columna si se cumple con una condición en otra columna?

Desde mi punto de vista seria algo así:

```
if(datos$item_type == "Household"){
    datos$item_fat_content = "None"
}
```

se supone que esto debería de funcionar bien, pero no lo hace. O es que tengo que usar una For??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `if` es una instrucción de control de flujo como el de cualquier otro lenguaje, cuando haces `if(datos$item_type == "Household")` solo se evalúa el primer elemento del objeto `datos`.

Para manipular el `data.frame` completo cuentas con la función base [`ifelse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html):

```
datos$item_fat_content = ifelse(datos$item_type == "Household", "None", datos$item_fat_content)
```

Esto se lee:

Asignamos a `datos$item_fat_content` la cadena `None` en caso que `datos$item_type == "Household"` sino le asignamos el mismo valor.

Otra forma más precisa de resolver esto sería:

```
datos[datos$item_type == "Household", "item_type"] = "None"
```

En este caso hacemos uso del operador de indice o extracción `[]`, seleccionando las filas deseada y asignado el valor `None` a la columna `item_type`, únicamente sobre las filas dónde `datos$item_type == "Household"`.

**Comentario**: R es un lenguaje que trabaja sobre datos vectoriales y tiene un mundo de funciones y herramientas que operan directamente con vectores, listas y demás colecciones de datos, todo esto hace que el uso del `for` sea innecesario la mayoría de las veces.

Comment: wao men, muchas gracias, implementare el codigo y te cuento como me fue